# Node JS module for Find other users feature

Tags: node.js, npm

I've started to create a Find other Users feature similar to facebook's search for people where it refines the search with each letter the user types. I have socket io implemented to transmit the data live, but I feel I'm reinventing the wheel. Is there an npm module that can do this?

Comment: I would say use plain ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive Autocomplete is the go-to module for this kind of thing although I have not used it myself, so I can only point you in the direction of the docs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocomplete.js

The example at the bottom of the page linked above does exactly what you described in your question.